# Isolating pytest tests from each other

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, fixtures

I'm working on a rapidly growing Python project. Lately, our test suite started being somewhat unmanageable. Some tests fail when the modules they are in get executed in the wrong order, despite being seemingly well-isolated.

I found some other questions about this, but they were concerned with fixtures:

[Pytest fixtures interfering with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226871/pytest-fixtures-interfering-with-each-other)

[test isolation between pytest-hypothesis runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956693/test-isolation-between-pytest-hypothesis-runs)

While we're using fixtures as well, I do not think the problem lies within them, but more likely in the fact that we use libraries where classes have internal state which gets changed by the test run, for example by `mockito-python`.

I originally come from Java world where this does not happen unless you explicitly make your tests depend on each other or do some crazy and unusual things. Following the same set of practices in Python led me to these problems, so I realize I might be missing some crucial rule of Python test development.

**Is it possible to tell `pytest` to drop/revert/reinitialize the internal state of all classes between various module runs?**

**If not, which rules should we follow during test development to prevent these issues?**

**Edit:** One of the issues we identified was that we had some objects set up at top level in the test file, which were created by `mockito-python`. When the tests were executed, the files are first all imported and then the tests are executed. What happened was that one test was calling `mockito.unstub()` which tears down all mocks in mockito's mock registry. So when the test was actually executed, another test had already torn down its mocks. This behavior is quite counter-intuitive, especially for unexperienced developers.

Comment: generally it's a bad sign if you have mutable global state, though sometimes it is necessary.  If you can identify where the global state is you can use fixtures to isolate and tear down after tests.  `yield` fixtures are a good way to manage globally mocking and can be used to reset global state as well

Comment: As the previous comment states, fixtures are the answer here. Set up and tear down your mocks in fixtures.

Answer (score 4):

In python it can happen easily that some state is modified by mistake.  For example, when assigning a list to a variable, it is easy enough to forget to add a `[:]` when it is desired that a copy of the list is created.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y = x    # oops, should have been x[:]
y[2] = 7 # now we modify state somewhere...
x
=> [0, 1, 7, 3, 4, 5]
```

One possible approach to at least more likely identify such problems could be to execute your unit-tests in random order.  I ran an experiment building upon the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006044/5747415:

```
import unittest
import random
def randcmp(_, x, y):
    return random.randrange(-1, 2)
unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = randcmp
```

As a result, the execution order of tests changed between the test executions.  If by mistake your tests happen to have dependencies, you might be able to figure it out this way, because certain execution orders would lead to failures.  Certainly, you would start on a small scale (only executing a small amount of tests), so you have the chance to more easily find the culprit.

Maybe worth trying...

Comment: Never thought to run tests in random order. That is an excellent idea to root out these issues!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to tell pytest to drop/revert/reinitialize the internal state of all classes between various module runs?

You can achieve this by using `importlib` to both [invalidate cached modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.invalidate_caches) and [reload imported modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) (thus refreshing the code & state).

This can be useful when code is required to run at the module level, for example in [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) where it's common to initialize `app` at the module level in `main.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

In this case `app` will be created whenever you import `from main import ...`. You may want to test initializing `app` in different ways, so in your test you could do something like

```py
def test_app():
    import main
    importlib.reload(main)  # reset module state
    # do something with main.app
```

This would reset the state of the `main` module during your test.